# if a go binary with debuginfo could cause performance degradation

Tags: go

I want to add debuginfo in kubelet binary, I'm not sure if it will casue performance degradation for kubelet.

Build a binary without debuginfo

```
go build -ldflags="-w -s" main.go
```

To build a binary with debuginfo, I use

```
go build main.go
```

When build a binary with debuginfo, I suppose it will only cause the binary larger which with more debug sections in the binary, but I'm not sure if the code performance will decline，can anyone help with this?

Comment: AFAIK stripping out the debug information is mostly about reducing binary size. Also it is used to make it harder to reverse engineer the code given the binary. At the same time it makes debugging a lot harder. I'd say the default is (or should be) to not strip them.

Comment: About performance: I don't think your question can be answered, but I'd tend to say that there is no performance impact -- at least not a significant one. You'd have to verify that for your use case yourself.

Comment: Don't do that: 1) having debug info merely means having more data in special segments of the executable image file; 2) should your kubelet crash, without debug info ready, the crash dump the Go runtime would produce would be severely limited in usefulness.

Comment: @kostix I believe OP is saying that the published kubelet binary has debuginfo stripped, and they're trying to build a version that includes debug info, not the other way around.

Comment: The debug info makes the file significantly larger. Copying larger files over the network is slower. Thus startup can be slower. As soon as your program is running, its memory use and speed isn't affected, becuase the debug info is not loaded (mapped) to memory.